# Concerns about moving media files to a CDN and impact on SEO

Tags: media, seo, cdn

I'd like to move all my media files to a CDN (Windows Azure is my best choice for now).

Two questions :

- How can I avoid SEO and redirections issues for the previously uploaded media files ?
- For the next media files I'll upload, isn't using a CDN bad for SEO and search engine ranking ?

Comment: I don't think media files are of any use to Google. They should hardly have any affect on moving.

Comment: @John images don't affect ranking ? That's great news if it's true :-)

Comment: Google cares only about alt, title tags in case of images. Though name of image may also matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is?

Putting all our images over on Amazon Cloudfront was the only way that we were going to get our images indexed by Google and keep our customer happy by having a responsive server that wasn't wasting time serving images instead of pages.

The media server cname was registered with Google webmaster tools, any search term I enter has quite a few high ranking images over in the image search which, since Google originally found them on our main website, provides a nice link back to the page where they were found.

It all ties together if you do it right.

Comment: It does not directly answer's OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

A *good* CDN will positively affect your SEO, as page load is a big part of Google's algorithm.

One thing to keep in mind with page speed, Google doesn't care abut page load from one place. They are looking for good global page load times. If you use a good CDN like CloudFlare then you should actually see a 20-30% increase in traffic from organic search.

I know I have.