# Should images moved to CDN be 301 redirected?

Tags: images, cdn, optimization, cname, google-image-search

I've seen a [couple different questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38838/concerns-about-moving-media-files-to-a-cdn-and-impact-on-seo) or [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78054/serving-images-on-cdn-allow-crawl-of-origin-or-cdn-or-both), similar to this, but they didn't really answer my question all they way.

I have a site I built for a friend about a year ago and I recently had all the static resources moved to a ***CDN***.

My concern here has to do with how *images* should be dealt with. For example on [this about page](http://disputebills.com/about) there is an image on that page that for the past to year the link has looked like this:

http://disputebills.com/assets/uploads/2016/01/medical-form.jpg

Now that it's on the CDN the link on the page has been changed to this:

http://disputebils16.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/assets/uploads/2016/01/medical-form.jpg

**MY QUESTION IS THIS**

Should the old images be 301 redirected? Currently they still exist on the server so both images will work, but in regard to SEO is it better to leave them how they are or redirect the old image links to the new ones. I also thought maybe even redirecting the old links to the page itself, but I'm not sure if that's a bad idea or not.

I've also read it's good to CNAME the url or use a conical header but I'm not sure if that's something to look into or not.

Comment: How does the CDN work?   Does it fetch the images from the main server and proxy them, or does it require that you upload the images to the CDN.   In a proxy situation, redirecting the content will likely break the CDN functionality because the CDN itself will be unable to access the images.